# NGINX - Proxypass limit inbound speed

Tags: nginx

I am currently using the following server block to proxy an IPFS server

```
server {
    server_name ipfs.mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://EXTERNALIP:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ipfs.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ipfs.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = ipfs.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name ipfs.mydomain.com;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

From what I tested this works to slow down the upload speed of the content to 50k

```
location /download/ {
    limit_rate 50k;
}
```

However the problem I have is the content is being downloaded to the server from the IPFS external server at a much much faster rate. How am I able to limit the speed of my server > IPFS to the same speed.